# Como usar o $_GET para pegar um conteúdo vindo de um link que foi enviado para o email de um usuário?

Tags: php, get

Eu enviei esse link para o e-mail de um usuário:

```
http://www.example.com/redefinir_senha.php?token=4kl_EIwmivsCg52TsBgWWgWMPsApjFTJL8oBUXPDoHE&uid=USER-ID
```

Na página redefinir_senha.php eu sei fazer o seguinte:

```
$token= $_GET['token'];
```

O negócio é que antes de usar o "token" para fazer o update da senha com minha **função DBUpdate** eu preciso pegar a nova senha do formulário que está nessa página também através do método POST.

Já usei o GET antes e  dentro desse IF abaixo, mas no final a senha não é alterada no banco de dados.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 

$token = $_GET['token']; // Já coloquei aqui e fora, já tentei usar sessão 
                         // ao invés    de simples variável e nada...

if (isset($_POST['senha'])){$senha = DBEscape($_POST['senha']);

$ativar = array('senha' => $senha);

$atualiza = DBUpdate('myway', $ativar, "token = '$token'");
if ($atualiza==true){
echo "Senha redefinida com sucesso!";
}
} else {
echo "Ocorreu um erro, entre em contato conosco!<br>";
}         
  }
```

Não é problema com a função de atualizar, pois estou usando ela em outra página e funciona normalmente.

Se dentro de minha função Update **eu simplesmente trocar** `"token = '$token'"` por `"email = 'qualqueremaildobanco@gmail.com'"` tudo funciona...

Comment: O token não está vindo na alteração da senha correto? Como está o `action` do formulário? Se não estiver usando o `submit` do formulário, esta adicionando o `token` no AJAX?

Comment: action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  Esse action eu preciso para postar a senha na mesma página. O token vem do link que o usuário clica no email.

Comment: A `Query String` aparece no `action`? Pelo que vi dessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127113/php-serverphp-self-to-include-query-string, o `PHP_SELF` não retorna a `Query String`, tente usar o `REQUEST_URI` como recomendado.

Comment: Olhei lá, mas não sei como aplicar. Usar request no lugar de post?

Comment: Não não, é só trocar o `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` pelo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` no `action` do form. Assim não perde a Query String que contém o token.

Comment: Cara, funcionou. Obrigado! Como isso funciona?

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta e explico ok?

Comment: Valeu! Tav'apertando minha mente isso...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como citado nos comentários, na sua página de redefinição de senha há um formulário com o a URL do seu script:

```
//Não sou expert em PHP, mas vou supor que está escrevendo a
//variável $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] no action do form

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ...>
    // Demais campos do seu formulário
</form>
```

O que deve ser renderizar como:

```
<form action="redefinir_senha.php" ...>
    // Demais campos do seu formulário
</form>
```

Nesse caso, houve a perda da `Query String`, necessária para fornecer os parâmetros que seu script necessita. No seu script tem:

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```

Esse parâmetro `GET` não existirá da forma que esta.

A primeira alternativa é trocar a `URL` que está no `action` do formulário, usando o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` em vez do `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php):

O `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` retorna o nome do arquivo do script que está executando, relativa à raiz do documento. Não incluindo a **Query String**.

O `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, retorna a `URL` fornecido para acessar a página atual, incluindo a **Query String**

Com a alteração seu formulário deve ficar:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" ...>
    // Demais campos do seu formulário
</form>
```

Que se renderizará como:

```
<form action="redefinir_senha.php?token=4kl_EIwmivsCg52TsBgWWgWMPsApjFTJL8oBUXPDoHE&uid=180488099954031df1897ac1.93258484" ...>
    // Demais campos do seu formulário
</form>
```

Ao submeter o formulário, o parâmetro `$_GET['token']` estará preenchido.

**Outra alternativa** que sugiro é incluir os parâmetros que precisa da URL e incluir como **input hidden** no formulário, e ai não precisa alterar o `action`.

Basta escrever seu formulário como:

```
// Podendo manter o $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ...>
    // Demais campos do seu formulário
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_GET['uid']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Que será renderizado como:

```
<form action="redefinir_senha.php" ...>
    // Demais campos do seu formulário
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="4kl_EIwmivsCg52TsBgWWgWMPsApjFTJL8oBUXPDoHE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="180488099954031df1897ac1.93258484" />
</form>
```

Para recuperar os valores:

```
$token = $_POST['token'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
```

As duas alternativas funcionam, basta escolher a que achar melhor.

Comment: Entendi cara! Perfeito! Eu estava perdendo o token mesmo... Se eu usar os "hiddens" o que preciso vai ser enviado da mesma forma, então resgato eles com o $_POST da mesma forma que faço com a senha! Sendo assim posso deixar o PHP_SELF... (y) MUITO SATISFEITO! Agora conheço o "REQUEST_URI"! Valeu!